# DateTime format to a WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I need some help.

1. My problem is,I have a textbox,I wanna write a correct DateTime form for it with "autostring". For example if i write into my TextBox,I want the program to write a . or a / after year,month automatically (in US DateTime form after 2-2 strings,in Hungarian after 4-2 - I am from Hun). If you can only show me a form in other DateTime like the US-GB-GE or any other country,that won't be a problem at all.Hungarian DateTime would be only a formality in my program.
2. I live in Hungary,didn't find any correct DateTime format for my Country. Format in here YYYY-MM-DD and not DD-MM-YYYY. Will it work if i simply reverse it or need to do anything else? I tried it,didn't seem to work,but maybe i did smth wrong.
   Please help!

Comment: Show us some code. Your question is unclear on it's own.

Comment: Once again (as Henk mentioned in your previous question) use appropriate control for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masked entry in a text box in WPF is not done easily.  If it's a requirement that the text box have the slashes or the dashes for the date as the user enters it, I would consider using [WPF Toolkit DateTime Picker](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker) or the [WPF Toolkit Masked Edit Text Box](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox), both of which are available on Codeplex as part of the Extended WPF toolkit.

If you still want to try masked text box editing on your own, here's an example I found that could be modified for a date format of your choice: [WPF Masked Text Box](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/masked-textbox/)

Comment: Installed the WPF toolkit,I can see it in the list of my references,but I can't see any new Control in my toolbox. Tried everything,what I saw on net. What is going on?:-/ It is installed correctly,But I can't get the controls to my toolbox,no matter what I do!

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding the DLLs as a project reference, and then set "Copy Local" to "Always" in the reference.  Then, re-build your solution, and maybe close and re-open your designer.  The new tools should appear (sometimes you have to restart VS)

Comment: There is something with my current project (I am sure I use.net 4.5 in it,but when I import .DLL and check the new controls,It says I can't use it,check my .net version),I don't know what is the problem,but if i start a new WPF project,I can see the controls. So I guess I will ctrl+c ctrl+v my code into a new project (It isn't problem at all,my database is code first also,so It won't take any time). Anyway,thx for help,I can make all of my criterium with MaskedTextBox and I only need to use around 4-5 rows of a freshly created code for it. Nice and Easy. You helped me a lot! Thanks!